# Why are my taxonomy icons in views showing for admin users but not for other users?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a site that uses **Views** to display node 'teasers' to users. They then click a node title to view the node itself. I have a search-based View as well as several list views that show different sets of the same nodes.

All the Views show **1-2 small icons** for the node, a linked title, and a description and sometimes a location and date. Everything was working fine...until it wasn't, and I have no idea what changed.

Actually, **everything IS working fine if you're logged in as the admin user**...*however for all other users one of the icons doesn't show anymore*. After weeks of troubleshooting **I've determined it has to be a module or database issue somehow**. I figured this because when I re-wrote my local development database with a backup from July the icons shows for all users now.

I've determined that all the modules on both development AND the production site are all the same and the same versions too. I tried changing the theme to **Bartik** to see if maybe that was causing a problem...doesn't work on Bartik either, so **it's not a theme issue**.

The images are both attached to the nodes as **term reference fields** (because they are coming from **taxonomies**). I've compared the two taxonomies settings and both are identical (except with different icons). I also have a **custom module** that gives recommendations to users and DOES show the icons to all users and works fine. So I know it's **not a matter of permissions** to see the images and I know they are there and working correctly when just using php in a custom module. Also I've made sure permissions on the Views are set to show to to whomever can view published content (and users can definitely see published content). I tried setting it to 'roles' also and that didn't help either.

I also examined the **SQL** for one of the Views thinking maybe that might be an issue, and determined the SQL is exactly the same in PROD and DEV. Here's the SQL:

```
    SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS 
field_data_field_icon_node_entity_type, 'node' AS 
field_data_field_price_node_entity_type, 'node' AS 
field_data_body_node_entity_type
    FROM 
    {node} node
    INNER JOIN {field_data_field_type} field_data_field_type ON node.nid = 
field_data_field_type.entity_id AND (field_data_field_type.entity_type = 
'node' AND field_data_field_type.deleted = '0')
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('resource')) AND 
(field_data_field_type.field_type_value = '4') ))
    ORDER BY node_title ASC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I'm now trying to figure out where the **database** problem might be. I've so far compared the following entries and they are all the same:

- taxonomy_vocabulary
- views-view
- taxonomy_index
- field-data-field-taxonomy-icon
- node

See my screenshots below to see what I mean. ADMIN users can see the little red icons while all other users cannot.

How results look for logged-in users:
[image]

How results look for anonymous users:
[image]

Not sure what else to look at. Thoughts? Suggestions?

I'm pulling my hair out here.

Comment: Please provide details on how you added the icons. Did you use a module? custom code? using views custom field? views template tpl.php using an if statement If tax = this then print icon?

Comment: @Sssweat ok I added that above. I was reminded of a custom module I'm using to auto-add the icons for our authors when they create a node...so I put that code in there.

Comment: can you disable your custom module to see if its conflicting?

Comment: In your view, what if you **change the access to role** instead of using permission, does that make any difference?

Comment: @No Sssweat I disabled the module and tried manually selecting the category (the tax. term) for a node and flushed caches. No change. I also changed access to role and set all roles to have permissions. Flushed caches. No change.

Comment: @No Sssweat I tried enabling every permission in my site. Regardless of what I try only admins can see the icons.

Comment: this is a head scratcher, try creating a brand new view that just has the icons to see if it also has the same problem.

Comment: @No Sssweat another excellent suggestion. Alas it didn't work. I created a new View and just added the title and group (category) field. In the preview it shows the icon...but when I save it and view it as anonymous user (zilch - well, just the title!). I turned on SQL also to see what that would look like and it's pulling both the fields correctly (or seems to be) with field_data_field_icon_node_entity_type and field_data_field_price_node_entity_type (the cost icon that does appear).

Comment: @No Sssweat I even tried removing ALL my styling from the page and the icons still don't appear. This is insane. I'm gonna try to disable various modules now.

Comment: @No Sssweat ok so get this, I deleted my database and re-created it with a backup I had many months ago. Now it works. But of course I've made a bunch of changes since then...

Comment: sounds like a module is causing this conflict.

Comment: perhaps. i compared all the modules from the DEV (working, with old database) to PROD (not working) and all the modules have the same version numbers! It must be a Views or Taxonomy issue though. Any idea of a more detailed way to troubleshoot those specific modules and perhaps roll them back?

Comment: does the DEV have the same amount of modules enabled as PROD?

Comment: incredibly, yes. do you think it's possible this problem could be created by bad data entry on the part of one of our authors? (ie. they input something in a wysiwyg text box they shouldn't have)

Comment: ok yes its probaby a module thing i think more and more...but what? i even tried using the bartik theme instead of my theme and the icons still don't show. i also tried unpublishing all content new in the past 3 months... still doesn't show...so i don't think its content/theme related.